# Update chat with MySQL on JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a chat system where anyone can go into the chat and send a message. The messages are stored in a MySQL database and my code looks like this at the moment ...

```
<script>
$('input[type=text]').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/chat.class.php",
      data: { steamid: "<?php echo $steamprofile['steamid']?>", message: document.getElementById("chatMessage").value },
      type: "GET",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
      alert("Message sent");
      // This is when the chat should update for everyone
    }).error(function() {
      document.getElementById('chat-box').innerHTML += '<span class="text-muted"><i>Could not send chat message at this time.</i></span>';
    });
  }
});
```

Basically, it inserts a new row into the MySQL table once you press enter.

As it is a chat for everyone, I need the chat to update for every user when anyone sends a message.

I know how to display all the messages and who sent them, but I need it to update whenever someone sends a message, for everyone.

I've done research but I can't find anything useful unfortunately and now I'm clueless.

I've thought of updating the chat every x seconds, but I want to make the chat as smooth and fast as possible and wondering what the best solution would be.

Have a good day

Comment: You can either have each page poll for new posts on a timed basis, or you can use sockets to keep an open connection between the server and the client's browser, and then have the server push new posts.

Comment: What would a good choice for a chat system like that? Honestly, I don't need to store all of the messages ever sent. I just need to store the 50 most recent ones. So whenever someone joins the chat they will see the 50 most recent messages whether they were offline when they were sent.

Comment: I recommend [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Answer (score 1):

So that is a read operation, and hence what you are trying is a write operation. Either you can do a continuous lookup to the server with a interval/timeout/ or initiate a rest call when last call was finished (success/error/timeout whatever). but better approach for this will be initiating a WebSocket Client and create and set up WebSocket Server in your backend and design it properly, so if it get any message from any client it will send that to all other client or something optimizer/ or something in schedule

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a realtime database like Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start and on your client side you can listen to messages being added using something like:

`commentsRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
  addCommentElement(postElement, data.key, data.val().text, data.val().author);
});`

With firebase you can create a serverless chat application.